# msxsl:script language="JScript" - process tree fragment?

Tags: xslt, jscript, msxml, msxsl

Suppose i have XML tree like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <val>10,1</val>
    </item>
    <item>
        <val>20,2</val>
    </item>
    <item>
        <val>30,3</val>
    </item>
</root>
```

How can i select tree elements inside msxsl:script function which is written on JScript?
Like this:

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="baator">
<![CDATA[
    function test(N) {
        //processing result tree fragment N here, for example i need to convert //item/val to numbers and return a complicate f(N)
    }
]]>
</msxsl:script>
...
<xsl:value-of select="baator:test(//item)" />
```

In official docs there are examples for C# language, but none for JScript. I tried to use same class names with no success.
It's important to use JScript because there are functions already written on it in production environment.
Thanks!

Comment: You will need to tell us which XSLT processor in which environment you use as both MSXML in the COM world as XslCompiledTransform in the .NET framework world support extension functions in JScript but the object models and type mappings of a node-set or tree fragment are quite different. With the sample you have given, the argument on the XSLT/XPath site with `//item` is a node-set of `item` elements. How that maps to a class or type on the JScript site depends on the XSLT processor so please tell us which one you use.

Comment: I create xslt/html templates for complex crm system, developed by a third-party company. The xslt transformation is performed on a server side that is written on ASP.NET. But i cannot tell for sure which XSLT processor is used (if there is more then one implementation in ASP.NET).

Comment: Try to run http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest2.xml in your enviroment and then tell us which output you get so that we know which XSLT processor you use. If you are using `XslCompiledTransform` then the mapping in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx indicates that a node set should be represented as an `XPathNodeIterator` in .NET code. If that does not work for you then we need to see your code.

Comment: The output is:  
    property name  property value  
    xsl:version  1  
    xsl:vendor  Microsoft  
    xsl:vendor-url  http://www.microsoft.com  
    msxsl:version  v4.0.30319

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your XSLT processor is a version of MSXML, like MSXML 3 or MSXML 6 which is used inside Internet Explorer as the XSLT processor, the API is the MSXML API documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. A set of nodes selected by an XPath expression would be represented as an `IXMLDOMSelection` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so you could script it as

```
function test(nodes) {
  var node;
  var sum = 0;
  while ((node = nodes.nextNode()) !== null) {
   sum += parseFloat(node.selectSingleNode('val').text.replace(',', '.'));
  }
  return sum;
}
```